Show thumbnails instead of icons - in one folder only
I'd like to have the contents of only one folder displayed as thumbnails, whilst the contents of all all folders - as icons.
I find it confusing seeing my files as images, however there are a few folders where I have only pictures - there, it would be great to see a thumbnail of the pictures and not just icons.
There's this menu in Windows but the setting there is global and not folder specific (it should be specific as I'm editing the options of the specific folder I'm in right now...).

Edit:  Changing this setting for any directory (on any drive) would apply the selected setting for all drives in the system.  I've actually tried putting both the root of C: and the directory I want to display differently (located in another, external drive) side by side, and clearly noticed that changing the setting for one, immediately affects the other.
I couldn't find a problem to this specific issue.
OS is Windows 10 Pro, version as below:

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Roy

Yours is a basic logic question: You need to apply one setting to everything, and a specific setting to one thing. Solve it this way:

Pick a folder that you want to display Icons in and open the dialog you have pictured in your question. I would recommend that you do this in the root of the drive.
Enable Always show icons, never thumbnails here and click Apply.
Click Apply to all folders, and confirm.
Open the folder you wish to see thumbnails in and open this same dialog.
Disable Always show icons, never thumbnails, then click Apply.

What you will have done is told the computer to show Icons in every folder EXCEPT for the one folder you want to see Thumbnails in.

Thanks !  Of course I've tried it (I didn't mention it because I thought it was obvious).  Logically, this is exactly what's needed to reach my goal.  Practically however, changing this setting for any directory (on any drive) would apply the selected setting for all drives in the system.  At least this is the behavior I clearly see here:  I put C: and the directory (located in another, extercal drive) side by side - changing the setting for one, immediately affects the other.

Please don't assume. We must take your words at face value because that's all we have to go on. I have tested and I see what you're saying. The Advanced Settings appear to apply everywhere, even if you don't click "Apply to all folders". I'll delete my answer in a few minutes because it clearly doesn't work the way I thought it had.
